# Efficient Implementation of Taylor Series for Sine

Tags: numerical-analysis, computational-physics, approximation

I am trying out a few forms of polynomial expression optimization, and I'd like to improve of what I've got, if anyone has anything they know is better.

Implementation 1:

$$x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}$$

To the best of my knowledge, this has 3 add/subtracts, 21 muls, and 3 divs.

Implementation 2:

$$x(1+x^2(\frac{-1}{3!} + x^2(\frac{1}{5!} + x^2(\frac{-1}{7!}))))$$

This appears to have 3 adds/subracts, 13 muls, and 3 divs. This is assuming that $x^2$ is precalculated. (I may have counted wrong here.)

Implementation 3:

$$x(1+\frac{x^2}{3!}(-1 + \frac{x^2}{5*4}(1 - \frac{x^2}{7*6}))))$$

This appears to have 3 adds/subtracts, 6 muls, and 3 divs. Edit: Again, assuming a precalculated $x^2$.

Note: In all my factorial calculations, I have not done the $*1$ final multiply.

Am I doing anything wrong here, or is there any way this implementation can be made more computationally efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taylor series is not a good way to do this; it takes a lot of terms to get reasonable accuracy.

I answered a [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5778442/224264) a while ago. Here's the body of the answer:

> Here are some good slides on how to do power series approximations
>   (NOT Taylor series though) of trig functions:
>   http://www.research.scea.com/gdc2003/fast-math-functions.html
>
> It's geared towards game programmers, which means accuracy gets
>   sacrificed for performance, but you should be able to add another term
>   or two to the approximations to get some of the accuracy back.
>
> The nice thing about this is that you should also be able to extend it
>   to SIMD easily, so that you could compute the sin or cos of 4 values
>   at one (2 if you're using double precision).

If you really really want to use Taylor series, check out "Fast Polynomial Evaluation" in part two of the linked slides; it provides some examples of [Estrin's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme).

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. It also solves the primary issue of finding a optimized way of evaluating said functions.